# Not adding object to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

Would love som help with this problem I'm having with objects that wont be added to arrays.

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSArray *katArr = [defaults objectForKey:@"kategorier"];
    NSMutableArray *kategorier = [katArr mutableCopy];

    [kategorier addObject:[katfield text]];
    NSLog(@"la till kat: %d", [kategorier count]);
    [defaults setObject:kategorier forKey:@"kategorier"];

    NSArray *bArr = [defaults objectForKey:@"bild"];
    NSMutableArray *bilds = [bArr mutableCopy];

    [bilds addObject:valdFarg];
    NSLog(@"la till pic: %d", [bilds count]);
    [defaults setObject:bilds forKey:@"bild"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The first object, "[katfield text]", is being added and NSLog output counts up.
The problem is that the second time I do it with the object "valdFarg", it is not working.
I have tried allocating memory for the array but that is not the problem, I think at least.

Thanks.

Comment: what is count? 0? you sure `bArr` is not nil?

Comment: Is it possible that the object in user defaults is corrupt? I guess that could happen.

Comment: @xlc0212 The count is 0, and bArr is not nil.

Comment: @PhilipSheard How do I know if it is corrupt?

Comment: try `bills = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:bArr]`

Comment: are u working with arc? try to alloc the array in didload and modify [bilds addObject:valdFarg]; with [bilds addObject:self.valdFarg];

Answer (score 0):

If NSMutableArray *bilds is nil [bilds addObject:valdFarg]; does not make bilds a mutable array with one object;

Instead of

```
NSArray *bArr = [defaults objectForKey:@"bild"];
NSMutableArray *bilds = [bArr mutableCopy];
```

do

```
NSMutableArray *bilds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"bild"]];
```

to make sure it is never nil and you always have a mutable array you can add to.

Comment: While it is true that `arrayWithArray:` seems to allow a nil argument this fact is nowhere documented. It also feels somewhat untypical that the method does not raise an exception (see `stringWithString:`).

Comment: stringWithString: is the exception that is why it's exception is probably documented, everything else like dictionaryWithDictionary: dataWithData: etc takes nil.

Comment: `stringWithString:` is documented to raise an exception. `arrayWithArray:` **is not documented** to work with a nil argument. It might even raise in a future OS release. It's at least bad style to rely on an undocumented behavior of a method.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you are using the wrong key, so it's returning you nil :

```
NSArray *bArr = [defaults objectForKey:@"bild"];
```

Is it not bilds instead of bild?

```
NSArray *bArr = [defaults objectForKey:@"bilds"];
```

Comment: I don't know who puts -1... but that's not stupid... since variable is bilds in his code... Sometimes it happen...

Comment: This answer should be in a comment, not as an answer. It's a question you are asking - you are not stating what the answer to the question is.

Comment: Ok sorry for that... I'm new. I just try to help. I took answer because I wanted to post some code which is better in answer mode. I just find it little mean to put so much minus in this because I was trying to help. And I didn't say completely wrong things... That could have been the issue...

Comment: Make sure you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) The -1 is more as an indicator to other people searching for answers than as a personal attack on you!